# Opening modal in using ajax is not working

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

I have here the sample project that will get the value of the id of an  attribute using ajax and then should show the modal using ajax.

The program that I've got is functioning well in terms of getting the id but my problem is the modal is not showing.

What I tested to know the problem is that I deleted the `class="modal hide"` in the modal and so the modal appeared below of the table and not in front of the whole page.

It just looked like another division under the table.

So now my problem is that the modal doesn't pop up. When the  is clicked nothing happens if there is an attribute `class="modal hide"` of the modal, but if there is no attribute like that it is working there is a modal but it is not a pop up.

It is like another division under the table.

What's wrong with my code?

```html
<a type="button" data-toggle="modal" id="11" class="push">Read more</a>
```

```html
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.push').click(function () {
        var res_id = $(this).attr('id');
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '../php-files/resolve.php', // in here you should put your query 
            data: 'post_id=' + res_id, // here you pass your id via ajax .
            // in php you should use $_POST['post_id'] to get this value 
            success: function (r) {
                // now you can show output in your modal 
                $('#mymodal').modal('show'); // put your modal id 
                $('.modal-body').show().html(r);
            }
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

```html
<!-- Modal -->
<div id="myModal"  class="modal hide fade in" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <!-- Modal content-->
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you set up a minimal example to demonstrate your issue? You can create a fiddle with that, and on JSFiddle there are instructions on how to make dummy AJAX requests.

Comment: Are you sure your request is successful? It could be that it is not and that is why those instructions never execute!

Comment: use    data-target="#mymodal" on your button

Comment: @Gacci yes i'm sure that it is working because I tested it without using toggle modal and it something shows on a div. but if I am using a modal it does not show.

Comment: @Sahil I cannot use data-target because I will miss the ajax function.

Comment: @Terry the main problem is that the modal does not show.

Comment: @SahilManchal thank you!!!! I tested it and that's the only thing that is missing on my code!!!!!!! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

In success function add this code

```
 $('#id1').modal('show'); // you
    $('#body').html(r);
```

Your model should be as below

```
 <div class="modal" id="id1" tabindex="-1"  role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel"  aria-hidden="true">
    ...
    <div id="body" class="modal-body text-center">
       <!--   loading modal.. -->
    </div>
    ..
    </div>
```

Comment: Thank you but the modal still does not show but the content of it shows except the modal. The content just shows on top of the navigation just like a text.

Comment: Thank you. I already made it.. all I was missing was just the data-target! Thank you!